# Authentication using BCrypt not saving hashed_password while using mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt

I was trying out Authentication in rails from scratch code.
I set up all codes according to[Railscast user authentication](https://github.com/railscasts/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised)

> BUT one major difference was in the tutorial , `sqlite3` database was
>   being used while I am using `mysql`

The signup is successful but no hashed password is being saved in the database.
Here is my controller code for create/signup-

```
def create
@user=User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to user_path(@user), flash: { success: "User Created Successfully!" }
else
  render "new", flash: { danger: "User Creation Failed!!" }
end
```

end

[image: Mysql database table snapshot]

Here is the model-

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :password_digest, confirmation: { case_sensitive: true }
  validates :name,presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

### Now when I click the Login button by entering valid details I get this error->

[image]

***Here is the SessionsController code also,***

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user= User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password_digest])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, info: "Logged In!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or Password invalid !"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

### Login Form:

```
<%= error_messages_for(@user) %>
<div class="card w-50 m-auto shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">

  <%= form_tag(sessions_path, class: "form-group row") do %>
    <div class="card-body mb-10">
      <%= label_tag :email %>
      <%= email_field_tag :email, "", required:true, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= label_tag :password_digest %>
      <%= password_field_tag :password_digest, "", required:true, class: "form-control" %>
    <div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <%= submit_tag("Log In" , name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary")  %>
      <%= link_to "Back", users_path, class: "btn btn-dark " %>
    </div>
  <% end %>


</div>
```

Please suggest me a wayout I have tried to correctly write all the necessary codes, where am I missing why this kind of problem happeing?
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What does your form look like? You also realize that this code is very old, almost 7 years, things have changed

Comment: I have added the code to add form @Eyeslandic

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong, use `password`. [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) takes care of turning it into a digest, that's the whole point.

By the way, you showed the login form, also change this for the signup form.

```
<%= password_field_tag :password, "", required:true, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: HI I changed all the occurances of password digest as password but now its showing another unexpected error `undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User:0x00007f2de59ccdd0> Did you mean? password=`

Comment: Remove the validates from your model

Comment: You must have it somewhere, do some "find in files" or whatever it's called in your IDE